# retrieve output from session array in button click php

Tags: php, arrays, session, button

i'm doing the download file in php.. i've shown all the file in a page and download when user click the download button.. the file name has been stored in an array session within a loop.. when the download button is click, new page downloadfiles.php is open and download the file.. problem is i can only pass the session array value manually.. how can i pass it according to user click on the button?

currently i using $file = $_SESSION['imagefilename'][0]; to manually download the first file in the database.. how can i automatically assign the [0] value based on user click?

display.php

```
<?php 
    //pass session email here
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image WHERE email='$email' ");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($image);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
        $_SESSION['imagefilename'] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image))
    {
        //get the image path
        $path = $row['path'];
        //get the image name
        $name = $row['name'];

        $_SESSION['imagefilename'][] = $name;
        $_SESSION['imgpath'] = $path;

            echo "<br>Your image: '$name' <br><img src='$path' width='300' height='200'><br><a href='/images/downloadfiles.php' data-role='button' data-theme='e' target='_self' name='download'>Download</a><br><a href='deleteimg.php' data-role='button' data-theme='e' target='_self'>Delete</a></br>";


    }
    }else
        echo "No image found!";

    ?>
```

images/downloadfiles.php

```
<?php
session_start();
    // Define the path to file

    $file = $_SESSION['imagefilename'][0];


   if(!$file)
   {
   // File doesn't exist, output error

   die('File not found');
   }
   else
   {
 // Set headers
 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
 header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");


 // Read the file from disk
 readfile($file);
 }



 ?>
```

i'm doing the download file in php.. i've shown all the file in a page and download when user click the download button.. the file name has been stored in an array session within a loop.. when the download button is click, new page downloadfiles.php is open and download the file.. problem is i can only pass the session array value manually.. how can i pass it according to user click on the button?

currently i using $file = $_SESSION['imagefilename'][0]; to manually download the first file in the database.. how can i automatically assign the [0] value based on user click?

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed the file's ID into the download link url:

```
echo "<br>Your[..snip..]<a href='/images/downloadfiles.php?id=$idx' etc...
                                                          ^^^^^^^^
```

and then retrieve it in the download script with:

```
session_start();

$id = $_GET['id'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['imagefilename'][$id])) {
    die("Invalid file id");
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** Hacker Friendly Code Detected :P

Answer (score 0):

Why do want to use sessions ?
Just send the image id as a get parameter and check the email after that.

display.php (in your while fetch_assoc)

```
<a href='/images/downloadfiles.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>' data-role='button' data-theme='e' target='_self' name='download'>Download</a>
```

downloadfiles.php

```
 $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
 $image = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM image WHERE id="' . $id . '"');
 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($image);
 if($numrows!=0)
 {
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
   if ($row['email'] == $_SESSION['email'])
   {
      // Header and readfile
   }
 }
```